# Is it possible to query a collection in a MongoDB database using Mongoose?

Tags: mongodb, mongoose

I have inserted documents already in my collection called 'exercises' through Atlas but I can't seem to find a way to retrieve those documents using Mongoose. Here is what I have written:

```
const exercisesRouter = require('express').Router()
const mongoose = require('mongoose')
const Exercise = require('../models/Exercise')

exercisesRouter.get('/', async (res, req) => {
  await mongoose.connect('mongodb+srv://nalanart:<password>@cluster0.2iplh.mongodb.net/workout-app?retryWrites=true&w=majority', { useNewUrlParser: true }, () => {
    console.log('Connected to DB')
  })
  const doc = mongoose.model('exercises', new Schema({}), 'exercises')

  doc.find({}, function(err, collection) {
    console.log(collection)
  })
  
})

module.exports = exercisesRouter
```

And I did replace < password > with my own password, so that's fine and I'm able to connect to my DB. When I use Postman to submit a get request to this endpoint, I get an UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: ReferenceError: Schema is not defined

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have:

```
  const doc = mongoose.model('exercises', new Schema({}), 'exercises')
```

but you just required 'mongoose', so that should be mongoose.Schema:

```
  const doc = mongoose.model('exercises', new mongoose.Schema({}), 'exercises')
```